# Sending a post query sent via HTTParty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, buffer, httparty

I'm working with the Buffer App API with HTTParty to try and add posts via the [/updates/create](http://www.bufferapp.com/developers/api/updates#updatescreate) method, but the API seems to ignore my "text" parameter and throws up an error. If I do it via cURL on the command line it works perfectly. Here's my code:

```
class BufferApp
    include HTTParty
    base_uri 'https://api.bufferapp.com/1'

    def initialize(token, id)
        @token = token
        @id = id
    end

    def create(text)
        BufferApp.post('/updates/create.json', :query =>  {"text" => text, "profile_ids[]" => @id, "access_token" => @token})
    end 
end
```

And I'm running the method like this:

```
BufferApp.new('{access_token}', '{profile_id}').create('{Text}')
```

I've added `debug_output $stdout` to the class and it seems to be posting OK:

```
POST /1/updates/create.json?text=Hello%20there%20why%20is%20this%20not%20working%3F&profile_ids[]={profile_id}&access_token={access_token} HTTP/1.1\r\nConnection: close\r\nHost: api.bufferapp.com\r\n\r\n"
```

But I get an error. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Not all error messages are alike. They usually contain at least a hint of what the problem is, and sometimes spell it out completely. In other words, please provide it.

Comment: Ah, OK, here you go:

`"{\"success\":false,\"message\":\"Nice try, but you need to write something!\",\"code\":1004}"` 

This is an API error, rather than a HTTP one obviously

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I reviewed the [API](http://bufferapp.com/developers/api/updates#updatescreate), and the updates expect the JSON to be in the POST body, not the query string. Try `:body` instead of `:query`:

```
    def create(text)
        BufferApp.post('/updates/create.json', :body => {"text" => text, "profile_ids[]" => @id, "access_token" => @token})
    end
```