# Trying to set up decoupled oauth for coinbase, code for token request failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, httparty, coinbase-api

I have been stuck on this for quite some time, I am doing decoupled oauth2 for coinbase and everything is working fine except when I get to the code for token exchange. I have the following lines of code in one of my rails controllers

```
@coinbase_user_token =   HTTParty.post("https://api.coinbase.com/oauth/token/",
        :headers => {"Accept" => "application/json"}, 
        :query => { 
            "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
            "code" => params["code"],
            "client_id" => ENV["COINBASE_KEY"],
            "client_secret" => ENV["COINBASE_SECRET"],
            "redirect_uri" => "http://fuf.me:3000/api/coinbase/token-callback"
        }
    )
```

whenever I send this I get the following response

```
"error"=>"invalid_grant",
"error_description"=>"The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to another client."}
```

I've also tried changing the request to model the curl request they have on their website

```
        @coinbase_user_token = HTTParty.post("https://api.coinbase.com/oauth/token/",
        :headers => {"Accept" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}, 
        :data => "grant_type=authorization_code&code=" + params["code"] + "&client_id=" + ENV["COINBASE_KEY"] + "&client_secret=" + ENV["COINBASE_SECRET"] + "&redirect_uri=http://fuf.me:3000/api/coinbase/token-callback" 
    )
```

but this results in the same response. Any help on what I might be doing wrong or another approach would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will probably be solved simply by changing

```
:query => {
```

to

```
:body => {
```

I'm not familiar with HTTParty, but [similar answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9312118/2623995) suggest that this will put the arguments in the POST body, rather than the query string.

> For Coinbase Wallet API endpoints, you can pass arguments in your requests, as params, form data or JSON with correct Content-Type header.

- ([ref](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#status-codes))

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't fix it, I am still getting the same response. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Bummer. Could you try capturing the request in a [request bin](http://requestb.in/), and then sharing the capture results with us at api@coinbase.com? Once we get this figured out I'll come back here to fix the answer.

Comment: sorry for taking so long to respond to this, not sure if you guys did something on your end up it's now working with :body. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem, glad you're up and running, thanks for letting me know! :)